# How do I login/authenticate through API on KACE 1000 System Management Appliance 7.0

Tags: python, python-requests

Here is my python code:

```
import requests

def main():
    username = 'test'
    password = 'test'
    org_name = 'Default'

    session = requests.session()
    session.params = {'password': password,
                      'userName': username,
                      'organizationName': org_name}
    session.headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
                       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                       'x-dell-api-version': '5'}

    login_path = 'SERVER/ams/shared/api/security/login'

    response = session.post(login_path)

    print(response)
    print(response.json())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am able to log in manually through the browser with the account test and password test as an admin. However, when running the above code I get

> < Response [401] >
>   {'errorCode': 29, 'errorDescription': 'Login Failed: Incorrect user name or password.'}

I've been stuck on this for more than an entire day at work. I need to get access to the API in order to run queries with scripts. I called customer support and they . made me wait for 1 hour before telling me no engineers were available. ANY help would be greatly appreciated. I want to be able to get a CSRF token with a status 200 response from the post request.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `params` argument sends the data in the URL's query string. According to the [api docs](http://support-public.cfm.quest.com/40686_K1000_7.1_API_Reference_en-US.pdf) the credentials should be sent in the body of the POST request, which means you should use the `data` argument.

```
session = requests.session()
data = {'password': password,
                  'userName': username,
                  'organizationName': org_name}
session.headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                   'x-dell-api-version': '5'}
login_path = 'SERVER/ams/shared/api/security/login'
response = session.post(login_path, data=data)
```

Note that `data` will url encode your data. If you want to send json formated data use the `json` argument instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is extremely helpful - managed to log in now.